# Map elements from list with items from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of "important" checkpoints which are passed by a user:

```
important_checkpoints = ['checkpoint_1', 'checkpoint_2', 'checkpoint_3', 
                         'checkpoint_4', 'checkpoint_5']
```

The term "important" means, that from all possible checkpoints ('checkpoint_1', ... ,checkpoint_99) the user can pass, I am only interested in the checkpoints listed in `important_checkpoints`.

Additionally I have a dictionary containing the checkpoints which have actually have been used by the users:

```
user_checkpoints = {"id_1": "checkpoint_11", "id_2": "checkpoint_3", "id_3": "checkpoint_4", 
                    "id_4": "checkpoint_45", "id_5": "checkpoint_68", "id_6": "checkpoint_1", 
                   "id_7": "checkpoint_1"}
```

**Solution to example:**
Now I want to get a dictionary which tells me which user-ID passed one of the "important" checkpoints:

```
{"checkpoint_1": [id_6, id_7], "checkpoint_2": [], "checkpoint_3": [id_2], "checkpoint_4": [id_3], 
"checkpoint_5": []}
```

**My not finished solution**
I was able to find passed important checkpoints (here: `['checkpoint_1', 'checkpoint_3', 'checkpoint_4']`) but I was not able to match the corresponding IDs.

```
activated_checkpoints_by_user = [] # activated_forms_for_user_concerns
for key in important_checkpoints:
    if key in list(user_checkpoints.values()):
        activated_checkpoints_by_user.append(key) 

>> activated_checkpoints_by_user
>> ['checkpoint_1', 'checkpoint_3', 'checkpoint_4']
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with your last sentence. Just a hint: Write down in human language what steps to do for a single checkpoint. Use that as a rough layout of your program. When you get this to work, go from a single checkpoint to all checkpoints using a loop.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that I know how to find all checkpoints listed in ``important_checkpoints `` and which can be found in ``user_checkpoints``. I will add it to my example to make it more clear

Comment: Please also clarify what "important" means for a checkpoint. Are there unimportant checkpoints as well?

Comment: Thank you. I will make it clear. Give me a moment, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to map the values in the dictionary user_checkpoints back to the keys.
In Python there is no direct way to do it but you can itemize the dictionary and use a loop to get the result you want:

```
result_dict ={}
for imp_checkpoint in important_checkpoints:
  result_dict[imp_checkpoint]=[user_id for user_id, checkpoint in user_checkpoints.items() if checkpoint == imp_checkpoint]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both solutions!!! If find this one slightly more intuitive, therefore I have chosen it as my way to go :)

Comment: This repeats the `user_checkpoints` iteration for every important checkpoint - that makes it O(N^2). The other answer is O(N), just by initialising the result dict first.

Answer (score 1):

If I've properly understood your question, this should solve your problem:

```
result = {}
for k in important_checkpoints:
  result[k] = []

for i,k in user_checkpoints.items():
  if k in important_checkpoints:
    result[k].append(i)

print(result)
```

The output is:
`{'checkpoint_1': ['id_6', 'id_7'], 'checkpoint_2': [], 'checkpoint_3': ['id_2'], 'checkpoint_4': ['id_3'], 'checkpoint_5': []}`

Comment: Don't use the names of built-ins like `map` as a variable name. Call it something else and obvious like `result` or `activated_checkpoints_by_user`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all important checkpoints present in the result, even if they were never visited, first create a pre-initialised dictionary of the important checkpoints, called `activated_important_checkpoints` below. The value for each will be an empty list `[]`.

Then iterate over the `user_checkpoints` and append each userid *only if* that checkpoint is important. Which you can check with a dictionary key lookup of `activated_important_checkpoints`.

Here's an almost english-to-python version of that:

```py
activated_important_checkpoints = {checkpoint: [] for checkpoint in important_checkpoints}
# {'checkpoint_1': [], 'checkpoint_2': [], ..., 'checkpoint_5': []}

for user, checkpoint in user_checkpoints.items():
    if checkpoint in activated_important_checkpoints:
        activated_important_checkpoints[checkpoint].append(user)
```

Value of `activated_important_checkpoints` after that:

```
{'checkpoint_1': ['id_6', 'id_7'],
 'checkpoint_2': [],
 'checkpoint_3': ['id_2'],
 'checkpoint_4': ['id_3'],
 'checkpoint_5': []}
```

Notes:

1. The initialisation of `activated_checkpoints_by_user` occurs once, and is O(N).
2. The next loop to go over all the user checkpoints occurs once, and is O(N).
3. The dictionary key lookup in `if checkpoint in activated_checkpoints_by_user` is O(1) due to how key lookups work for dictionaries. For lists, it's O(N).